# How to retrieve source code from .war on grails

Tags: grails, war, decompiler

I lost my sourcecode of my grails project is there any way to retrieve 
the sourcecode from the war file. Maybe a decompiler, I'm not sure
Please help.

Comment: Are you unable to get it from Local history of IDE, if you are using one, and the project is not deleted as a whole?

Comment: I did a factory reset on my computer and I forgot to save the source code so all I have left is the war file

Comment: @ocespedes hi, can you guide me? have you get back your source code?

Answer (score 1):

JD-GUI (http://jd.benow.ca/) is the best decompiler I've used, and it's pretty good with classes compiled from Groovy. But what you get is far from the original code since it includes a lot of extra code that the Groovy compiler adds, and also code that is added by AST transformations.

It's likely going to be less time to rewrite the app from scratch.

Comment: i just create a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233799/grails-get-all-file-from-war/49234540#49234540

but someone said its not possible