# Grails: get all files from War

Tags: grails, war

I am using Grails 3.1.1

Last month, I had my project, but my hard-disk became corrupted because of a bad sector. I tried bringing my hard-disk to a "Recovery DATA"'s store.

But that store cannot recover my data, so my project's data is gone now.

But I still have the War file on my customer's server.

I just want to know: Is it possible to get my project back from a War file?

My War file is still running on the server, but all my source code is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to recover your entire project, including source code, from a WAR file. The WAR contains the compiled version of your code, not the source.

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any option and need to rewrite the application again, I'll suggest some ways:

Remove your hard-disk from laptop/desktop. purchase HDD internal sata to external USB case for desktop/laptop hard disk. which connects with connectors with circuit(Sometimes this helps you in boot-sector error also).
Connect it to the laptop and check is it showing HDD. If yes check data is available not. If HDD size showing correctly but data not available then you can recover data with " EaseUS Data Recovery" software.

**If all above fails?**

Copy your project war from server to local computer.
Install WinRAR or any other unzip software.
Select and open your war file with it.

[image]

See above screenshot,

Where `assets` folder contains js, css, images and all your other files.
which may be minified if you set `minifyJs = true` and `minifyCss = true` in your `application.yml`

Now, see very important folder called `WEB-INF`

[image]

See above image which contains two folders:

1. `classes` : This is very important folder which contains your controllers class files and gsp files.
   Controller files are `.class` files where for each action from controller will generate separate `.class` file. You can de-compile dot class files using many online/offline tools. 
   In case of `gsp` you will get original files.

Also you will get `application.yml` and other files as it is.

Hope it helps you.